# How to check a radio button programmatically in dynamic radio group?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of radio buttons. I want one to be selected when the application first launch.

Then when I will select some other radio button from the radio group that will be deselected.

Here's my code:

```
for (x in taskTypes) {
        var radioButton = RadioButton(context)
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { button: CompoundButton?, b: Boolean  ->
            if (b) {
                ......

            }
        }

        taskRadioGroup.addView(radioButton)
    }
```

Comment: are the radio buttons being dynamically added ??

Comment: Yes! As I shown in my code.

Comment: please check my solution below

Answer (score 2):

If you use `radioGroup`, previously selected `radioButton` should be automatically deselected. If you want a particular `radioButton` to be selected when activity is launched you have just have to add the following line in `onCreate()`:

```
yourDesiredRadioButton.isChecked = true;
```

Comment: `previously selected radioButton should be automatically deselected` -> I also though this way, but my personal test doesn't agree to this assumption... Not sure why...

Comment: @ariefbayu Is this happening when the `radioButton`s are generated programmatically? How did you solved it then? One option may be to set `isChecked` to false manually to every other `radiobutton`s.

Comment: check my answer, it's by `check`ing using the `radioGroup` instead of the button itself...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it always `check` the first RadioButton even when ALL radio is added inside a RadioGroup. My test also confirm your bug (maybe not bug, I just not sure why).

Here's my solution to your problem:

```
var radioGroup = RadioGroup(applicationContext)

for (i: Int in 0..4){
    var radio = RadioButton(applicationContext)
    radio.setText("button position ${i+1}")

    radioGroup.addView(radio)
    Log.d("LOG", "Working on radio ${i+1}")
}

radioGroup.check(0)

linearParent.addView(radioGroup)
```

Noticed how I set the first radio by executing `check(0)` of the `radioGroup`. This is because whenever I set if from the `radio` itself, that radio will always be in `checked` state:

```
//this code I placed inside for loop is somewhat broken...
if(i == 0){
    radio.isChecked = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTag();` method to provide a unique identification for all the buttons in your group and check/change the properties by checking their tags using `getTag()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the first `RadioButton` to be selected you can do this:

```
var isChecked = true;

for (x in taskTypes) {
    var radioButton = RadioButton(context)

    if(isChecked){
        isChecked = false;
        radioButton.checked = true;
     }

    taskRadioGroup.addView(radioButton)
}

 taskRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { button: CompoundButton?, b: Boolean  ->
        if (b) {
            ......

        }
    }
```

Comment: It remains checked all time even if I press another button

Comment: is `taskRadioGroup` is of type `RadioGroup` ?

Comment: Yes it's the main RadioGroup under which all radio button views are added

Comment: that is probably because you are setting `checkedChange` listener to individual radio button and not on the whole `RadioGroup`. Try the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I want one to be selected when the application first launch**

On create method

```
 hardradioButton!!.isChecked = true
```

**make listener of your radioGroup**
On create method

```
 radioGroup!!.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
```

**implement OnCheckedChangeListener**

```
override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup, checkedId: Int) {
        when (checkedId) {
            R.id.hard_radiobuttonm -> {
                //do whatever
            }

            R.id.ok_radiobuttonm -> {
               //do whatever
            }

            R.id.easy_radiobuttonm -> {
               //do whatever
            }


            else -> {
            }
        }

    }
```